# simple upload of image in database for sign up user

Tags: php, database, image, pdo

using php and pdo i was able to make a sign up page but with out saving image

```
$firstname = trim($_POST['fn']); //at a minimus clear whitespace.
        $lastname = trim($_POST['ln']);
        $username = trim($_POST['un']);
        $password =  trim($_POST['pw']);
        $confirmpassword=  trim($_POST['cp']);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO registration (fname,lname,username,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bindValue(1,$firstname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(2,$lastname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(3,$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(4,$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED...";
        }
```

i found this [tutorial](https://phpacademy.org/topics/pdo-image-upload-form-doesnt-store-image/30912) but its too complicated for me to understand and it was not explained clearly i am looking for ideas or tutorial that is easy to understand on how to upload image..any idea is appreaciated

form

```
<form method="POST" action="crud.php">
                <tr>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" name="image" />
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="fn">
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="ln">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="un">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="pw">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Confirm Password</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="cp">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="button" type="submit" value="Back" name="back"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="button" type="submit" value="SignUp" name="signup"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td><div style="font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo $error; ?></div></td></tr>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to achieve that:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){ 
    $folder = "upload/"; 
    $file = basename( $_FILES['image']['name']); 
    $full_path = $folder.$file; 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $full_path)) { 
        echo "succesful upload, we have an image!";

        $firstname = trim($_POST['fn']); 
        $lastname = trim($_POST['ln']);
        $username = trim($_POST['un']);
        $password =  trim($_POST['pw']);
        $confirmpassword=  trim($_POST['cp']);

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO registration (fname,lname,username,password, img_url) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bindValue(1,$firstname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(2,$lastname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(3,$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(4,$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(5,$full_path,PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED...";
        }else{
            echo 'YOUR REGISTRATION COULD NOT BE COMPLETED...';
        }

    } else { 
       echo "upload received! but process failed";
    } 
}else{ 
    echo "upload failure ! Nothing was uploaded";
}
```

In the query I have included a field called `img_url`.

The PDO insert query is executed once the image is uploaded successfully.

Comment: @satinekianne you are welcome, you can learn more about it here http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` in this line the `'image'` is the name of the button right sir?the `name="image"` of the input button?

Comment: Yes exactly it should match the name of the input file tag

Comment: sir can you look at update i dont get why i get undefined index ive search in net and you said the image is the name in the input but why do i get undefined index in here?any other ideas?

Comment: Add this to your form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: last question sir how do i correctly name a folder for example in my case my using local host..what i did is `C:\Users\satinekianne\xampp\htdocs\images\\` `but i get error  failed to open stream: No such file or directory in`

Comment: sir no problem i got the image i used `\\` instead of `\` i got uploaded now thank you for your advice and answers

Comment: can you please check my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235309/create-and-select-the-database-and-create-multiple-table-in-that-database-in-pdo if you can help me out.

Comment: Hi, i went through it can you tell me your goal. Why do you want to create a database trhough code? And also what is the issue exactly

Comment: i think its best to do it like that..are there any drawback to doing it like this?im not sure which is better
the code i answered there can be used if you create database before hand in myphpadmin
i want to make it that even if you dont make a database in myphpadmin it will still work

Comment: also the important i want to make is the multiple tables i cant make multiple tables even if use the sample code and change table names

Comment: What type of project are you working on? I ask because you need good reasons to do this. But hey who am I to judge? The problem is you are creating the connection with a dbname . You should remove that and try again using root. It will work

Comment: website with admin backend i want to create the back end for admin users.when the admin runs the admin page it will automatically create the database with tables.but i cant create multiple table just one is being create and i had to create the database manually in localhost..i dont know how to create database when i run it on real server so i want the code to do it.

Comment: let me know when you try that

Comment: sir sorry for late asking try what sir i actually am reading your comment until now but i cant understand what you mean what do you mean remove dbname and use root?i will name my database root?

Comment: can you meet me in the chat @satinekianne http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59553/discussion-between-meda-and-satine-kianne

Comment: i have a question, what is the possible error when i get `echo "upload received! but process failed";` so i know how to deal with it is it folder problems?

Comment: Most of the time its due to permission issue, it could also be the folder not existing. But its not obvious to guess turn on error reporting. `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: And always dump your data when debugging for example `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: why is it working it localhost when in server its not anymore i dont get any error in local host sir.

Comment: did you check the permission

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a simple PHP upload() function. Here's an example http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp